# I'm getting weird output reading a txt file in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I want to read a line out of a txt file. simple thing:

```
character*200:: line
open(20,file='test.txt')
read(20,*,iostat=rerr) line
write(*,*) line
```

and then I'm getting this:

```
 Ù Û ýe Ù Û         ýe         ¼Þe                    HÞe Þ  HÞe É@é    ■  ■  ╠Úe     ªé ¶Þe     , ýe  # ¨àªw        é ýe           └ é   Úe ╬  ÈÞe Ô|v
```

I did it the same way month ago, having no problems.
now I'm using g95 compiler. Is there missing something

Comment: If you remove `iostat=rerr`, or check the value of `rerr`, what happens?

Comment: If I'm removing the iostat:
At line 67 of file grossprogramm.f90 (Unit 20 "test.txt")
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Comment: Never saw this messege before

Comment: the value of `rerr` is `-1`

Comment: You have an error reading from the file and the value of `line` is not defined by the read.  Please look at [mcve] for us to help you further.

Comment: Commenting further on @francescalus, if you are wondering where the values come from, they represent an interpretation of some uninitialized memory block which represents your `line`.

Comment: what do u mean with "the value of line is not defined by the read"

Comment: The `read` command very likely errors because the file is not in the *current working directory* where you run the Fortran program or because the file is empty.

Comment: The end of the file was reached before the value of `line` could be read.  As a result, there's nothing with which to set the value.  And to add to the previous comment, you can open the file with `open(20,file='test.txt', status='old', access='read', position='rewind')` to help debug.

Comment: its not empty and in the same folder

Comment: Rule 1 for debugging Fortran i/o statements: use the intrinsic capabilities (such as `iostat`) to get diagnostic information, and **use** the diagnostic information.

Comment: What is in the input file?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a rewind earlier.

thx for help